# Preventing jQuery errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jquery-plugins

I am a Wordpress plugin developer and I just have a quick question regarding jQuery errors.

My plugin gives the user the ability to create a slideshow on their site, which involves loading jQuery and its own script. This is all done correctly using correct Wordpress functionality, etc. No problems here.

However, often other plugins don't use the correct functionality which can result in jQuery being loaded twice on a page, and sometimes even three times. Another issue is users who have been tinkering with jQuery plugins themselves and, for example, made reference to a function that doesn't exist which as a result throws a jQuery error and destroys my plugins (slideshows) functionality.

Just wondering if there is anyway to work around this that I maybe am not aware of. Is it possible to force a function to ignore errors or something similar? It's such a pain trying to explain to users that the plugins scripting isn't at fault but is suffering as a consequence of an external error. Troubleshooting this can be extremely difficult as well when the user isn't competent with Javascript or jQuery at all.

Most of all, its a real pain to have to deal with on a daily basis. For sure, jQuery being loaded more than once is the most common error, and it would be nice to try and eradicate it as much as possible to spend less time troubleshooting more time developing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can we please see some examples and code

Comment: It's not really possible to give any specific examples. Other than jQuery being loaded more than once, other kinds of errors would be scripts referring to a function that doesn't exist. Like if a script did `jQuery('.element').myCustomFunction();` only 'myCustomFunction()' does not really exist. Often users would install other jQuery based plugins and make reference to their functions externally, but fail to remove them when they decide to get rid of the plugin, and hence we are left with references to undefined functions.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to overcome multiple jQuery loads, each load init the jQuery object thus delete any function and properties you extended the jQuery object.

Just try tell them what the...

You can use `window.onerror` to catch scripts errors(Not that I know how can it help you):

```
window.onerror = function myErrorHandler(errorMsg, url, lineNumber) { 
    // Code...
    };
```

[window.onerror on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM%3awindow.onerror)

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
try {}
catch {}
```

If you force all the questionable code to run within try {}, the errors should not halt other scripts.  This still won't fix double/triple loads of jQuery and/or misuse of plugins...